# Problema em converter Foto Base64 no Android

Tags: java, android

O Problema é o seguinte, eu tiro a foto certinha e seto ela na activity, até ai tudo bem, mas depois de converter ela e enviar para o servidor e decodificar, só aparece apenas parte da foto:

**Código de tirar a foto**

```
private Integer ImageHeight = 520;
private Integer ImageWidth = 520;

            // Cria o caminho do arquivo no sdcard
            file = SDCardUtils.getPrivateFile(getBaseContext(), simpleDateFormat.format(new Date())+".jpg", Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            // Chama a intent informando o arquivo para salvar a foto
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);

Bitmap bitmap = ImageResizeUtils.getResizedImage(Uri.fromFile(file), ImageWidth, ImageHeight, true);

Foto = Utils.ConvertPhotoBase64(bitmap);
```

**Codigo de conversão para Base64**

```
public static String ConvertPhotoBase64(Bitmap bmp) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    Log.i("FOTO64", Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT));
    return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Será que o problema não ta nesse resize 520x520?

Comment: Brother eu já alterei isso pra diversos tamanhos, e sempre a mesma coisa, as vezes aumenta e diminui o os tamanho dos traços depois de decodificada. Um outra observação, quando tiro foto de uma parte preta, na hora de converter da erro "A aplicação parou"

Comment: Você já tentou por uma Thread diferente, pois o android nao trabalha na mesma thread a conversão de imagem, assim como o acesso ao WS. 
Dê uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10594695/6405917

Answer (score 1):

Tente essa abordagem abaixo:

```
public static String getStringFromBitmap(Bitmap imagem){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, baos); // bm is the bitmap

    byte[] photo = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(photo, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Comment: Acho que teu problema está no "Base64.DEFAULT".

Comment: continua a mesma coisa brother, só aumentou um pouco a quantidade de imagem na foto.

Comment: Cara, estranho, eu uso essa abordagem e funciona...Já viu se a imagem vem certo da câmera?

Comment: opa, consegui aqui, o problema é que o Código Base64 era muito grande, e o campo do BD era do tipo text, eu alterei pra long text e deu certo, vlw pela ajuda!

Comment: Da hora! Cara, você tá salvando as imagens no banco? Podias usar a área de cache do app (uma dica só hehehe), aí evita fazer o encode e decode

Comment: Vlw, mas é pq eu preciso salvar no servidor mano, não sei se seria legal eu criar o arquivo no servidor, tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Depende cara, pq no final das contas, vai trafegar na rede em bytes...é que depende a quantidade de fotos e que tipo de banco de dados você tem, bem como o relacionamento e acesso as fotos...

Se você depender muito de fotos, e toda vez que enviar, precisar da foto e tem banco a vontade, use o banco...
Se você tiver banco de dados limitado, e tem processamento para transformar a imagem em texto toda vez, e não tem dependencia de enviar sempre...use foto....
Enfim, depende hehehe